# Changed DNS server, now can't connect to internet on Safari, Chrome or App Store

Tags: safari, google-chrome, internet, dns, firefox

I'm using Mac 10.7.5. Attempting to speed up my internet connection, I downloaded [namebench](https://code.google.com/p/namebench/) and changed my DNS server per the suggestion given by namebench.

After restarting my computer, I can no longer connect to the internet on Safari, Firefox, or the App Store, although Chrome works just fine. Is there anything else I need to configure to enable internet browsing on these browsers?

Btw, namebench recommended I use the nameserver `205.171.2.65`.

Comment: What happens if you change the DNS server back?

Comment: Or, use the google nameserver 8.8.8.8 ?

Answer (score 2):

I always use OpenDNS when troubleshooting DNS issues, try using 208.67.222.222 and/or 208.67.220.220 as your DNS servers on your computer. Alternatively, try setting the network interface on your computer back to auto-obtaining DNS servers from your router via DHCP.

System Preferences > Network > [Network Adapter being used (WiFi or Ethernet usually)] > Advanced > DNS tab > delete any manual entries under "DNS Servers" and you should see a few entries in light grey (those are given to your computer via DHCP) Then click "apply" and you should be all set